# PHP compare dates returns true

Tags: php, date

I have the following date from a dates array:

```
  $expiryDate = date('d F Y', max($expiryDates));

  echo $expiryDate . ' < ' . date('d F Y'); // outputs: 01 January 2021 < 06 January 2020
```

I'm trying to compare if this date is less than todays date but its returning true?

```
 if ($expiryDate < date('d F Y') {
      // do something
 }
```

01 January 2021 is clearly greater than 06 January 2020 so why is it returning true

Comment: ISO8601 is a date format that allows for numerical comparisons.

Comment: String comparison?

Comment: convert them to unix timestamps and compare the timestamps instead. ```strtotime($expiryDate) < time()``` - strtotime() tries to guess what time format it is, but the proper way to do it is to use DateTime::CreateFromFormat(...)->getTimestamp() instead (CreateFromFormat() does not guess what the format is, so it's safer in case strtotime()'s guess is wrong, which certainly can happen)

Comment: You wouldn't do maths like `'One' + 'Two'`. Don't do the same with dates. PHP has a dedicated `DateTime` class and several functions that support Unix timestamps.

Comment: @mario the following doesn't work either  date('Y-m-d', $expiryDate) < date('Y-m-d') . I thought Y-m-d was valid ISO8601 format?

Answer (score 1):

If the date formats for both your dates are different you can use, strtotime to compare both dates.

```
$d1 = "10-08-16"; 
$d2 = "2011-11-20"; 


$dn1 = strtotime($d1); 
$dn2 = strtotime($d2); 


if ($dn1 > $dn2) 
    echo "$dn1 is latest than $dn2"; 
else
    echo "$dn1 is older than $dn2"; 

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing strings, thats the problem.
You can use `DateTime` class to do what you want.

```php
$now = new DateTime();
$yesterday = new DateTime('yesterday');

# It will return 1 that is true
echo $now > $yesterday;
```

You can find more examples in https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.examples-arithmetic.php

Answer (score 1):

you can use strtotime to compare the dates

```
 $expiryDate = "01 January 2021";

    if (strtotime($expiryDate) < strtotime(date('d F Y'))) {
        echo "expiry date is less than current date";
     }else
        echo "expiry date is greater than current date";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use correct format for comparison and use below comparison format.

```
$expiryDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", max($expiryDates));

if ($expiryDate < date("Y-m-d H:i:s") {
      // do something
 }
```